# How to read a file line by line remotely in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, remote-access

Let's say I have a file located on a given url (and no possibility whatsoever to do anything on the server hosting that file).

Can a .NET client application can read it line by line without downloading the file entirely? If so, how?

Comment: Do you mean without download the file to whatever system you're running on?  Just keeping the contents of the file in memory, without saving it?

Comment: @JosephRT yeah that was my point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, you'll need to pull the entire file down to your local machine. There's no way around that. But you don't have wait to read the entire file all the way to end before you start processing data at the beginning:

```
using (var request = WebRequest.Create("www.example.com/data.csv"))
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var str = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var rdr = new StreamReader(str))
{
    string line;
    while ( (line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       //process each line here
    }
}
```

But I would also look for a dedicated CSV parser that can accept a `Stream` as a constructor input. If you're planning on just using `string.Split()` or RegEx to look at the data, those are both much slower and have lots of gotchas.

I'm actually tempted to build this into a method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> DownloadLines(string URL)
{
    using (var request = WebRequest.Create(URL))
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var str = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var rdr = new StreamReader(str))
    {
        string line;
        while ( (line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // make sure we yield a *different* variable (defined in the loop) each time
            var result = line;
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
foreach(var line in DownloadLines("www.example.com/data.csv"))
{
    //process each line here
}
```

And it would also work with linq operators:

```
var result = DownloadLines("www.example.com/data.csv").
             Where(l => l.Length > 0).
             Select(l => l.Split(','));
```

(Not that I endorse splitting on a comma... this is just a quick example).

Comment: Thanks that's a great answer!
Actually it was not specifically for a csv file in that case.

Comment: is it possible to use Reactive Observable to read the lines asynchronously in order to have a kinda of Asynchronous IEnumerable like some sort of asynchronous streams?